# Windows Azure SDK v1.6 does not contain csrun.exe, where can I download?

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-.net

I've downloaded and installed the official Windows Azure SDK v1.6 but for some reason csrun.exe (needed for running a package locally) is not in the bin directory with all the other exe files like cspack.exe etc. I have tried reinstalling and still did not get the executible. Is there anywhere to manually download this file, google wasn't any help...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is installed by the new v1.6 SDK into the directory

C:\Program Files\Windows Azure Emulator\emulator

Answer (score 3):

Just an update to this, looks like this is installed to the following location now.

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Emulator`

Answer (score 0):

This question was prompted by my attempts to follow the post here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brmeena/archive/2010/08/06/how-to-deploy-azure-roles-in-net-4-0-on-development-fabric.aspx about how to deploy to the dev fabric.

Andrew Patterson is correct in his answer above and I've marked it so, but I also found that I could run the tool from the Windows Azure Command Prompt even when I couldn't find the .exe (I still can't get Windows 7 search to behave)

Sharing here for my own recollection as well as to assist anyone else who might run into this issue.